# Armazenamento de dados WEBSOCKET e PHP

Tags: php, websocket

Eu me deparei com uma dúvida, eu tenho um servidor WebSockets escrito em PHP e preciso armazenar informações que o usuário envia para o servidor, e que esse dado possa ser recuperado apenas pela sessão atual entre o usuário e servidor.

Pensei em SESSIONS mas acho que nao é uma boa escolha, qual a solução?

Answer (score 1):

Dependendo da quantidade de informações, utilizar sessions pode não ser a melhor idéia. Caso queira uma alternativa, você pode salvar no banco de dados, tendo como referência o id da sessão atual ([`session_id`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-id.php)) ou então um número único salvo na `$_SESSION`, como por exemplo, `$user_id + time()`.

```
id | id_sessao | info1 | info2 | ...
 1 |    234234 |   ... |   ... | ...
 2 |    345354 |   ... |   ... | ...
```